# Why am I getting the error: "FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists"?

Tags: python, windows

Why am I getting error, if my script creates a folder? I am using Python on Windows 7.
The error:

> FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: [path to the file or folder in question]

The problem is that file and folder were not there.

Comment: Apparently a file or directory with the given name already exists. What else can anyone say about this?

Comment: If you are running the script again and again it creates folders again and again and it is not allowed to keep two folders of same name. So thats your error. If you want to create again then you need to keep different names for folders for different running instances.

Comment: @ErykSun the problem is that folder and file were not there. but it is not interesting, already) I solved. Thanks)

Answer (score 12):

As the comments point out, the folder already exists. You seem to think that attempts to create a folder that already exists should simply do nothing. But that is not how Windows sees it.

To avoid the error message, check first to see if the folder exists. Before the code that creates the folder, do

```
if not os.path.exists("name of folder"):
```

Comment: but what if I want to just overwrite it?

Comment: You can't overwrite a folder with a file. And I'm not sure what it might mean to overwrite a folder with another folder. .

Comment: create a folder with different contents but with the same name

Comment: Two ways to create a folder with different contents but the same name: (1) Delete the entire folder with its contents with `shutil.rmtree()` and then create the new folder you want. (2) Delete the original contents of the folder and put your files in the (now empty) original folder.

Answer (score 9):

I just encountered this same issue.  This thread helped me solve the problem, but the following clarification might help someone:

For me, the misunderstanding came from `shutil.copytree(source, destination, symlinks, ignore)`.

I read `destination` as being the place where my copied tree will go.  In reality, it creates that location and then copies the tree there.  So if your destination directory already exists, like mine did, you'll get the error.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 7):

I just encountered a slightly more subtle version of this, this might help someone else.

I was creating a folder with:
`os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(my_filename), exist_ok=True)`

Which should create the folder, but not error if it already exists.
I'd run this numerous times with no problem.

Ran it again, and got an error:

```
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: '\my\folder\path'
```

Eventually worked out that I had kept the output folder from a previous run for comparison, by renaming it to something else.
Which shouldn't have caused a problem, but I still had one of the files from that folder open in Notepad. So since there was still an active reference to the folder the OS was throwing an error.

Closed the file in Notepad an re-ran, worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, had forgotten to close an image viewer for an image in the deleted folder, that was it in my case.

Comment: thanks, exactly what was happening to me. Surprisingly the folder was correctly renamed without any error and had disappeared from the file system, but still able to cause the error in Python.

Answer (score 2):

i had this error when i tried to create pathtree and then copy files there.
the actual problem was that - there was not a folder that already exists.

instead , there was a extension less file with same name.

so python cannot distinguish between file and folder here.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when using makedirs to create one last folder in a path. I used mkdir instead and solved my problem.

BEst regards!