# Unable to extract some files from zip file

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, zip, unzip

I have made a python script which takes the latest files from university e-class (lectures in pdf formats, scripts etc) via requests and downloads them. After downloading it automatically extracts the zip on the specific folder i want. But the extraction function ***sometimes*** it gets stuck on the same files.

The function is this:

```py
import zipfile
from tqdm import tqdm

zipnm = 'Διαδικτυακά και Φορητά Πληροφοριακά Συστήματα'
quartls = '6'


def extractZip(zipName, quartInd):
    with zipfile.ZipFile('./'+zipName+'.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
        for member in tqdm(zip_ref.infolist(), desc='Extracting '):
            try:
                zip_ref.extract(member, './'+quartInd+'° εξάμηνο/'+zipName)
            except zipfile.error as e:
                print(e)
                    
                    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    extractZip(zipnm, quartls)
```

When running on terminal it throws this:

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\192.168.1.200\[REDACTED]> python .\test.py
Extracting :  39%|███████████████████████████                                          | 11/28 [00:00<00:01, 12.04it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\192.168.1.200\[REDACTED]\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    extractZip(zipsd, quartsd)
  File "\\192.168.1.200\[REDACTED]\test.py", line 12, in extractZip
    zip_ref.extract(member, './'+quartInd+'° εξάμηνο/'+zipName)
  File "C:\Users\[REDACTED]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1616, in extract
    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Users\[REDACTED]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1683, in _extract_member
    os.mkdir(targetpath)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Δεν είναι δυνατή η δημιουργία ενός αρχείου όταν αυτό το αρχείο υπάρχει ήδη: '6° εξάμηνο\\Διαδικτυακά και Φορητά Πληροφοριακά Συστήματα\\Εργαστήρια\\Lab 5 - Introduction to PHP'
```

When I'm trying to extract the zip file manually, it sticks on 2 files that I either can retry or abort the files from extracting. Although the other files that already exist show me the options to replace them. My question is, why is this happening on these 2 files and not letting me to replace them like the others? Are the files corrupted (although I checked their size and looking if EOF is missing but nothing suspicious)?

P.S. I don't want on my script file to check if exists to exclude them I just want to find the source of the problem so I can act accordingly.

P.S.#2:
The files that get extracted are actually in an Ubuntu server machine which I access via Samba on Windows and then I run the script or doing anything with the files.

Comment: Check the permissions for the existing files

Comment: Nope, nothing suspicious everything is as it should be. Checked also with ubuntu terminal.

Comment: WinError with code 183 usually means that the file already exists (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491021/why-am-i-getting-the-error-fileexistserror-winerror-183-cannot-create-a-fil)